# Existing remote github repo not found via command line push

Tags: github

```
OS: Mac Mojave
```

I have a personal GitHub account that I contribute to, and some other corporate accounts that I contribute to as well.

On my private account, I created a private repo, and what I would like to do, is check some source code, that I have on my local disk, into that repository.

From a Mac terminal, I made sure I was in the directory I wanted to check into the empty private repo, and then I did the following:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "checking existing files into my private repo"
```

I then went to my private repo, and copied the URL, let's say:

```
https://github.com/myaccount/myPrivateRepo
```

I then did the following:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myaccount/myPrivateRepo
```

and then did:

```
git remote -v
```

And got the following response:

```
origin  https://github.com/myaccount/myPrivateRepo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myaccount/myPrivateRepo (push)
```

Which I assumed means: everything checks out OK

Then I tried to push, using:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Which gave me the following error message:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myaccount/myPrivateRepo/' not found
```

## Any ideas?

I trued changing the remote to:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myaccount/myPrivateRepo.git
```

and when I tried to push, I got the following error:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote you add should be of this form:

```
git@github.com:myaccount/myPrivateRepo.git
```

Also set your git email address to match those of your github account:

```
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Full Name"
```

You can also edit these by editing the `.git/config` file.

Finally, make sure your SSH public key is correctly set up:

https://github.com/settings/keys

Your public key should be located in `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. You can print it with:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you don't have an SSH public key yet, then follow this guide:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Also make sure the SSH public key and email address is set correctly.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the SSH key from my new Mac to my GitHub SSH keys. My checkins, using an IDE, were working, because the IDE was using its own settings, and I told it to use the proper GitHub SSH key